# Was bedeutet „in seinen Schoß nehmen” im bestimmten Zusammenhang?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich übersetze gerade ein quasi Reisebuch und verstehe diesen Satz nicht:

> *Doch in seiner flüssigen Form nimmt es uns sanft in seinen Schoß, wäscht jeglichen Stress und Druck wie nichts von uns.*

Es handelt sich hier um Wasser. Was bedeutet „in seinen Schoß nehmen”?

Answer (score 3):

Mit dem "Schoß" ist in diesem Zusammenhang "die beim Sitzen durch Unterleib und Oberschenkel gebildete Körperzone" ([Zitat Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scho%C3%9F)) gemeint.

Beispielsweise nimmt eine Mutter ihr Kind in ihren Schoß, um es zu trösten.

In dem Buch wird dies offensichtlich im übertragenen Sinn verwendet.

Comment: Danke! Das war ein bisschen zu abstrakt für mich. Jetzt alles klar :)

Answer (score 2):

"in den Schoß nehmen" literally means to take someone on their lap; to their bosom; or into the fold (as in to accept someone as part of the family). When referring to water and using the terms "wäscht jeglichen Stress und Druck wie nichts von uns", it would mean to "envelop" or "wrap" you in serenity and security. Think of going to a "Hot Spring" and the warm, bubbly water wraps around you and gets rid of the stress in your body.